# Get shipping methods magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone help me how to fetch the all shipping methods available in system->config->shipping Methods programatically.

I  have used the below code:
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

Get the result like below:

but iam unable to find what are methods names:

Result:

```
[freeshipping] => Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping Object
    (
        [_code:protected] => freeshipping
        [_isFixed:protected] => 1
        [_rates:protected] => 
        [_numBoxes:protected] => 1
        [_freeMethod:protected] => free_method
        [_customizableContainerTypes:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => freeshipping
                [store] => 
            )

        [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
        [_origData:protected] => 
        [_idFieldName:protected] => 
        [_isDeleted:protected] => 
        [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[tablerate] => Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate Object
    (
        [_code:protected] => tablerate
        [_isFixed:protected] => 1
        [_default_condition_name:protected] => package_weight
        [_conditionNames:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => package_weight
                [1] => package_value
                [2] => package_qty
            )

        [_rates:protected] => 
        [_numBoxes:protected] => 1
        [_freeMethod:protected] => free_method
        [_customizableContainerTypes:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => tablerate
                [store] => 
            )

        [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
        [_origData:protected] => 
        [_idFieldName:protected] => 
        [_isDeleted:protected] => 
        [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all active shipping methods titles like this :

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
foreach ($methods as $shippingMethodCode => $shippingMethod) 
{
  $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippingMethodCode.'/title');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, In the above code getActiveCarriers means

Comment: Hi @sami please find the updated question

Comment: @shivashankarm I updated my answer

Comment: @shivashankarm tell me if it works ;)

Comment: iam getting titles like this:

Comment: Flat Rate
Free Shipping
Economy Shipping
DHL (Deprecated)
Federal Express
United Parcel Service
United States Postal Service
DHL
M2E Pro Shipping
UPS
Pickup

Comment: but i have some titles are with different names

Comment: Flat Rate
Free Shipping
Table Rates
Custom Shipping Price
M2E Pro Shipping
UPS
USPS
FedEx
DHL (Deprecated)
DHL

Comment: These are your shipping methods titles  in system->config->shipping .Each shipping method has a title in the admin configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81587/discussion-between-sami23-and-shivashankar-m).